# E and Z configuration

Tags: cis-trans-isomerism

[image]

In the above we need to find the configuration of the two double bonds whether (*E*) or (*Z*) according to me the one with the cyanides should be (*E*) and the other (*E*) however my book say that the correct answers are (*E,Z*) (in the same order as above) . Please explain how ?

Comment: Please show your precedence order; that way it would be easier to spot an error, if any.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Cahn-ingold-Prolog sequences?

Comment: I get (*E*) for both alkenes as well.

Comment: Chemdraw gives (E) for both alkenes also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct; the answer in your book is wrong. I get (*E*) for both alkenes.

For the alkene on the upper right:

- $\ce{COOH}$ has precedence over $\ce{CH2OH}$ because the first carbon atom is bonded to $\mathrm{ \{O,O,O\}}$ and the second is bonded to $\mathrm{\{O,H,H\}}$.
- Clockwise around the ring has precedence over counterclockwise. While both initially are $\mathrm{\{C,H,H\}}$, the next carbon atom clockwise is $\mathrm{\{C,C,H\}}$ while the next carbon atom counterclockwise is $\mathrm{\{C,H,H\}}$.

For the alkene on the lower left, the nitrile groups win in both cases:

- On the left: $\mathrm{\{N,N,N\}}$ versus $\mathrm{\{N,H,H\}}$
- On the right: $\mathrm{\{N,N,N\}}$ versus $\mathrm{\{C,C,H\}}$

Comment: I was thinking along those line, but wanted to confirm isn't it priotities decrease clockwise?

Comment: Around the ring from the alkene in the upper right, clockwise > counterclockwise since CCH > CHH at the second carbon atom out.